# how to collect multiple row from codeigniter active record return as first row

Tags: php, codeigniter

i try to implode an array return row from sql, but i cant couse i have return like this..

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => tag 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => tag 2
        )    
)
```

but i want return like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => tag 1
    [1] => tag 2
)
```

and this is my model

```
public function gettags($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('tags.name');
        $this->db->from('tags');
        $this->db->join('posts_tags', 'posts_tags.tag_id = tags.id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('posts', 'posts.id = posts_tags.post_id', 'left');
        $this->db->where('posts.id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

help me guys..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arr = array
(
    0 => array( 'name' => 'tag 1' ),
    1 => array( 'name' => 'tag 2' )    
);

print_r(array_column($arr, 'name'));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => tag 1
    [1] => tag 2
)
```

[Reference](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/00e8173cc8de286527175c1fcfbf179b170f0117)

Comment: it works... thanks bro..